# angular default route with nginx

Tags: angular, nginx

I have a website `www.mysite.com` based on Angular 7 + nginx.

I have a default route for this angular app in the routing module:

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/index', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

So when I go to `www.mysite.com`, I am given `www.mysite.com/index`.

But when I got to some non-existing route, e.g. `www.mysite.com/oops`, I am given `www.mysite.com` instead of its index page.

And the following is my nginx setup:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you expect to happen when going to the path `/oops`, and why? You haven't posted any route matching this path.

Comment: @JBNizet There is no route for it so I would like it to give me `www.mysite.com/index`.

Comment: Then you need to configure a route that redirect from 'oops' (or from '**', which matches any path) to '/index'. The route you posted only redirects from '' to '/index'. And '' is not equal to 'oops'.